# Debugging IronPython in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, ironpython

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to debug my IronPython program. I've got IronPython and PyTools installed already.

While debugging, when I hover over a variable, say `tenants_path`, the value that's shown is `IronPython.Runtime.ClosureCell`. Why is this happening?

Comment: What would you expect the shown value/type/.. to be? Could you provide a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rectify this issue, I needed to right click on the solution, and choose `Properties`.

In the `General` tab, ensure that `Interpreter` is set to `IronPython 2.7`.

[image]

In `Debug` tab, ensure `Launch mode:` is set to `Standard Python launcher`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IronPython doesn't generate debugging information for its generated code by default, so VS just does the best it can.

If you're running `ipy.exe`, then you should run with the `-X:Debug` command-line option; if you're embedding, you'll need to pass "Debug" as `true` when creating the engine.